# what is difference between strapi content type and component?

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, strapi

I'm new user of strapi. While reading docs I got confused between content type and component.What is  the difference between these two?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why did you research? In the first googling I have tried you can find [this tutorial](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/getting-started/quick-start-tutorial.html) when you can understand the differences.

Comment: Actually firstly I did followed this documentation but, these two elements are used in same way. That's why confused.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A **Content Type** is a data structure that is used as a collection of specific content.

Could be Articles, Restaurants, Products, etc...

A **Component** is a data structure (also) that could be used and re-used in many different **Content Type**.

Example if you have Article and Product **Content Types** in your app, and you want to manage SEO tags for both of these **Content Types** you will create a SEO **Component** and use it in your Article AND Product **Content Type**

You will not have to create the same SEO data structure in both **Content Types**.

Answer (score 9):

Alternatively you can say that a **Content Type is a model** and a **Component is a custom / composite field** of one or more models.

Examples for content types could be:

- Restaurant
- Article
- Product

Examples for components could be:

- Opening hours (e.g. of a restaurant)
- Meta tags (e.g. of articles or products)